# UI Automation tools for windows (web page embedded in a windows app)

Tags: user-interface, testing, automation, automated-tests

We have a webpage(html) embedded inside an outlook addin. We have tried to automate UI testing using AutoIt and MS UI Automation framework in the past with the help of redemption to open/close outlook etc.. But we are having a problem accessing the elements inside the webpage within the addin (we are able to access Windows elements).

Does anybody know any automation tool/framework that can help us?

Answer (score 0):

Give [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) a try. Start with the [tutorials](http://sikuli.org/docx/tutorials/index.html).

I can't think of any other solution, as you're working in a very custom situation.